# when using accepts_nested_attributes_for to save two models the following error [Unpermitted parameter:] shows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I linked the following two tables.
I want to send the written data from the form to two different tables and  save it.
But I can't save too the child table.

I'm a beginner and I tried for two days.but I don't know.
Can you please help me?

**bird table**

- id
- name
- breed
- sex ...

**bird_condition table**

- id
- ave_weight
- body_shape
- ...
  (bigint "bird_id")

---

Version Rails 6.0.0

---

```rb
#app/models/bird.rb
class Bird < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bird_conditions, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bird_conditions, allow_destroy: true :reject_bird_condition
end
```

```rb
#app/models/bird_condition.rb
    belongs_to :bird, optional: true
end
```

```rb
#app/controllers/birds_controller.rb
class BirdsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bird,only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :correct_user,only: [:edit, :destroy]

  def index
    @birds = current_user.birds.order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def new
    @bird = Bird.new
    @bird.bird_conditions.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @bird.update!(bird_params)
    redirect_to birds_path,notice: "upload"
  end

  def create
    @bird = current_user.birds.new(bird_params)
    if @bird.save
        logger.debug "bird: #{@bird.attributes.inspect}"
        redirect_to birds_path, notice: "create"
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @bird.destroy
    redirect_to birds_path,notice: "delete"
  end

  private

    def set_bird
      @bird = current_user.birds.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @bird = current_user.birds.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to birds_path if @bird.nil?
    end

    def bird_params
        params
        .require(:bird)
        .permit(
          :name,
          :breed_id,
          :sex,
          :birthday,
          :personality,
          :appeareance,
          :srarus_flg,
          :lost_day,
          :lost_place,
          :day_of_death,
          :image,
          bird_conditions_attributes:[
            :id,
            :ave_weight,
            :body_shape,
            :hospital,
            :medical_history,
            :medication,
            :insurance,
            :estrous_behavior,
            :estrous_personality,
            :bird_id
          ]
        )
    end
end
```

```rb
#app/views/birds/_form.html.erb
<div class="container">
    <%= form_with model: bird, local: true do |f| %>
            <table class="table-bordered">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <tr>
                        <th><%= f.label :name %></th>
                        <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><%= f.label :breed %></th>
                        <td><%= f.collection_select :breed_id, Breed.all, :id, :name, include_brank: 'select' %></td>
                    </tr>
〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜abbreviation〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜
                        <%= f.fields_for :bird_condition do |condition| %> 
                            <%= render partial: 'form_condition', locals:{condition: condition}%>
                        <% end %>
                </div><!-- .form-group -->
            </table><br>
                <%= f.submit nil, class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
    <% end %>
</div><!-- .container -->
```

```rb
#app/views/birds/_form_condition.html.erb
                <div class="form-group">
                        <tr>
                            <th><%= condition.label :ave_weight %></th>
                            <td><%= condition.number_field :ave_weight %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><%= condition.label :body_shape %></th>
                            <td>
                            <%= condition.radio_button :body_shape, :medium %>
                            <%= condition.label :body_shape, :普通%>
                            <%= condition.radio_button :body_shape, :slim%>
                            <%= condition.label :body_shape, :痩せぎみ%>
                            <%= condition.radio_button :body_shape, :bony%>
                            <%= condition.label :body_shape, :痩せ%>
                            <%= condition.radio_button :body_shape, :chubby%>
                            <%= condition.label :body_shape, :太りぎみ%>
                            <%= condition.radio_button :body_shape, :fat%>
                            <%= condition.label :body_shape, :肥満%>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><%= condition.label :hospital %></th>
                            <td><%= condition.text_field :hospital %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><%= condition.label :medical_history %></th>
                            <td><%= condition.text_field :medical_history %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><%= condition.label :medication %></th>
                            <td><%= condition.text_field :medication %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><%= condition.label :insurance %></th>
                            <td><%= condition.text_field :insurance %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><%= condition.label :estrous_behavior %></th>
                            <td><%= condition.text_field :estrous_behavior %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><%= condition.label :estrous_personality %></th>
                            <td><%= condition.text_field :estrous_personality %></td>
                        </tr>
                </div><!-- .form-group -->
```

```
#error（log）
Unpermitted parameter: :bird_condition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form you have `:bird_condition` but in your `params` you have `bird_conditions_attributes` ... you just need to adjust the params  in your controller:

```rb
def bird_params
  params
    .require(:bird)
    .permit(
      :name,
      ...
      bird_conditions: [ # Use `bird_conditions` here.
        :id,
        ...
     ]
   )
end
```

Comment: I chenged [ _form.html.erb ]
before <%= f.fields_for :bird_condition do |condition| %>
after <%= f.fields_for :bird_conditions do |condition| %>

I have solved the problem.
thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm so glad you got it working @AyakaMoronaga! If this answer helped, please use the green checkmark to mark it as the correct answer!